# Modeling nested entities in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, thrift, cql

What is the best way to model nested entities in Cassandra, preferably in one Column Family? For example, Contacts with list if emails and phones:

```
{
"id" : "",
"first_name : "",
"last_name : "",
"emails" : [
    {
    "type" : "",
    "email": ""
    },
    {
    "type" : "",
    "email" : ""
    }
],
"phones" :[
    {
    "type" : "",
    "phone" : ""
    },
    {
    "type" : "",
    "phone" : ""
    }
]
```

}

I googled that Composite Types should be used instead of Super Columns, and there is also support for wide rows in CQl3 in the just released 1.2, but none of these seem to support several arrays in one entity, or I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store arrays directly as column value in json form (my manually marshaling/unmarshaling it).

or check this out:

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3_collections